# How to calculate time delta in pandas dataframe?

Tags: pandas

```
       ip  app  device  os  channel          click_time  is_attributed  
0   83230    3       1  33      888 2017-11-06 14:32:21              0
1   17357    3       1  19      379 2017-11-06 14:33:34              0
2   35810    3       1  13      379 2017-11-06 14:34:12              0
3   45745   14       1  33      888 2017-11-06 14:34:52              0
4  161007    3       1  13      379 2017-11-06 14:35:08              0
```

Here is the dataframe and I want to add one column which represents the time (seconds) delta value between every specified condition.
For example, let's take os-channel as an identifier and the **timedelta** in line-3 (**os=33&channel=888**) should be the time gap that is from the record last seen **os=33&channel=88**, which can be found in line-0. So the **timedelta**  should be the gap between **2017-11-06 14:34:52**   and **2017-11-06 14:32:21**. Is there is no **os=33&channel=888** before, the outcome should be Nan.
So how can I realize this in pandas ?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `click_time` is already `datetime`

```
df.groupby([“os”, “channel”]).click_time.diff()
```

Create a new column

```
df.assign(click_diff=df.groupby([“os”, “channel”]).click_time.diff())
```